# How to derive this equation for the Bohr radius involving the mass of the proton?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

My quantum mechanics book is talking about Bohr radius and gives an alternate equation that takes into account the mass of the proton. Namely,

$$r(n) = (1 + (M_\textrm e / M_\textrm p)) \cdot ((\epsilon ^*\cdot h^2)/ (\pi \cdot M_\textrm e \cdot e^2)) \cdot n^2$$

I have tried multiple times and am unable to derive this relationship. How would I go about doing so?